# Is there a way to simplify "if x == 1 and y == 2:"

Tags: python-3.x, simplify, simplification

Is there a way to simplify:

`if x == 1 and y == 2 and z == 3:`

`if x == 1 and y == 1 and z == 1:`

`if x == 1 or y == 2 or z == 3:`

---

`if x == 1 or x == 2` is simplified as `if x in [1, 2]:`

Comment: By using De Morgan's rules?

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks allot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your examples is **not** like the others. The `and` form can easily be simplified:

```
if x == 1 and y == 2 and z == 3:
```

becomes:

```
if (x, y, z) == (1, 2, 3):
```

However, the `or` form can't be made any neater. It could be rewritten as:

```
if any(a == b for a, b in zip((x, y, z), (1, 2, 3))):
```

but that's hardly *"simplified"*.

Comment: Sorry for raking up this question again, but can `if (x,y,z) == (1,1,1):` also be simplified as `if {x,y,z} == {1}:`. Is it correct ?

Comment: Why not try it and see?